# Using itertools.permutation where r > n

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am trying to generate all permuations of a set of items and the my R needs to be larger than the size of the set of items

Here is an example :

```
itertools.permutations ("ABC", 4)
```

this always returns 0 items as R > N.

I want this

> [A, A, A, A]
>
> [A, A, A, B]
>
> [A, A, B, A]
>
> [A, B, A, A]
>
> ...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to want the permutation, but the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

```
itertools.product("ABC", repeat=4)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing up the misunderstanding